# Dataset returns only first datable column names in rdlc report. How to get all the columns from all the datatables?

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset, rdlc

Let's say I have a store procedure that returns three data tables. For example:

```
Table 1

Month Day
Jan   12
Feb   15

Table 2

Id  Name
1    Jason
2    James

Table 3

Student Phone
Jason   +222
James   +515
```

In my rdlc report dataset I have only Month and Day Column which comes from the very first datatable. How to get all the column names from all the datatable?

Comment: Try to use LINQ to store column names inside an array: `var columnNames = ds.Tables[n].Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(x => x.ColumnName).ToArray();` (`n` stands for `DataTable` index inside `DataSet`). Then, you can retrieve them using `foreach` or other extension methods.

Comment: I think you haven't understood my problem. My problem is i need those column names in my rdlc report data.